# Is it useful to answer old questions?

Tags: discussion

When I am looking at questions, I see the related questions over to the side. Recently I have been clicking on them and adding my own two cents. Then I realize that the questions is a few weeks or months old and the original person may never even see it. Is it considered valuable to answer these sort of question (for the sake of future visitors?) or is it simply vanity and I should pass on them after a certain period of time.

Comment: I am really tempted to answer this question "No" four years after it was asked.

Answer (score 9):

I would definitely answer the old questions.

For one, a new answer "bumps" them to the top of the front page.   Frequently, a new answer to an old question will revive a question and give it a breath of fresh air including many new insights.

Stack Exchange also encourages this through the [necromancer badge](https://money.stackexchange.com/badges/44/necromancer).

Answer (score 4):

I think yes -- if it's a good answer, I will always upvote it, regardless of how old the question is.

However, this assumes the original question is interesting enough for me to click on in some way -- if it's a really bad question (title, etc) or an extremely obscure topic. However, this can sometimes be fixed with editing..

Thus, since **anonymous and low rep now have the ability to submit edit suggestions**, I would "punch up" the question through judicious editing when answering, to maximize the chances of people seeing both the question and your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only if the new answer adds real value. If the new answer *looks* good, but reading all the others shows that the new one added no new details at all, it really offered little more than a bump and clutter.

Comment: There's no harm in adding an answer even if its only improvement over others is that it "looks" better and in fact I much prefer reading answers that are well formatted and organized nicely.

Comment: Kenny, I respect your opinion, but disagree. If you answer, and content is good, another member should offer some kind editing/formatting, not an attempt to plagiarize your content. In fact, when I see a great answer that's just missing one important point, I'm likely to just add it. No OP has even rolled one back on me, as they never conflict with his intent.